# Java - Swing GUI doesn't load

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've been trying to learn java for a few weeks now, and I'm working on a pretty simple autoclicker.
The clicker itself works, but my problem is that my GUI never shows up.
The GUI runs just fine when I run the GUI file itself, but when I'm trying to run it from my main program (different file) it never shows. The clicker works fine all the time though. I'm sure the problem is something really simple that I have simply missed, but this is now my 4th day without any clue on what might be wrong with it, so decided I'd ask here.

Beware - the code is really messy atm, because I've been trying pretty much everything possible to get it working.

This is the code in the main program trying to run the GUI.

```
package autoclicker;

import java.awt.AWTException;

/**
 * The main program for the autoclicker.
 */
public class AutoClicker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Click click = new Click(true);
        click.clicker();
        try {
            Swingerinos sw = new Swingerinos();
            sw.initialize();
        }
        catch (AWTException e) { e. printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }
    }
}
```

And this is the whole GUI file.

```
package autoclicker;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;


public class Swingerinos extends Click implements WindowListener,ActionListener {

    private int numClicks = 0;
    TextField text;

    private JFrame frame;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=181,19
     */
    private final JLabel lblAutoclicker = new JLabel("AutoClicker");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Swingerinos window = new Swingerinos();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Swingerinos() throws AWTException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 109);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Toggle On / Off");
        text = new TextField(20);
        text.setLocation(100, 100);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener( this);
        btnNewButton.setToolTipText("Toggles the  autoclicker on / off.");
        panel.add(btnNewButton);
        panel.add(text);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        toggle();
        numClicks++;
        text.setText(""+numClicks);
    }


    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

}
```

I know the GUI file is really messy (there's 2x initialize(), one in the main program and one in the GUI file, and lots of other stuff, but I'm just too confused as for what to do now.

EDIT: I added the whole main program code, also this is the code for the autoclicker.

```
package autoclicker;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class Click {
    private boolean active;
    private Robot robot;

    public Click(boolean active, Robot robot) {
        this.active = active;
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public Click() throws AWTException {
        this(false, new Robot());
    }

    public Click(boolean active) throws AWTException {
        this(active, new Robot());
    }

    //TODO: add click.toggle() to somewhere and control da clicker
    public void toggle() {
        active = !active;
    }

    public void clicker() {
        while (active) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.setAutoDelay(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is bad: `catch (AWTException e) { System.exit(-1); }` and is the equivalent of flying blind. This is some better: `catch (AWTException e) { e. printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }` At least look at what exceptions are being thrown, if any.

Comment: Next, your goal should be trying to isolate your problem. One way to do this is by reducing the code in your program until you've pared it down to the bare minimum that demonstrates your problem. This will both simplify and expose your problem both for you and for us. Then post that runnable code here.

Comment: I just ran your code and I do get two windows popping up

Comment: Wow, I just tried running it without running the autoclicker object and it worked too. Hmm.

Comment: Maybe your `invokeLater` is never getting invoked on your machine but it is on @Richard Koetschruyter's?

Comment: This is the whole main program http://www.hastebin.com/lupeculada.java (Don't know how to do code in comments) and removing the Click click = new Click(true); and click.clicker(); indeed causes the GUI to open. What's up with that?

Comment: Well, the clicker() method probably has an infinite loop, or at least, never returns.

Comment: *"(Don't know how to do code in comments)"*  [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30152375/418556) instead.

Comment: @JBNizet Looking at the newly posted code, containing a seemingly non-terminating while-loop, it seems you were right. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @11684 mainly by laziness. I would feel forced to also comment on all the other things that are wrong in the code (threading, extending Click rather than using it, etc.) Feel free to answer.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding JB Nizet's comment(s) into an answer.

## The immediate cause:

When the JVM calls your code, it is run on the main thread. It calls `main(String[])`, as you know. You posted two main methods, only one of which is relevant to your nothing-is-happening problem: `AutoClick#main(String[])`. Let's go through it:

```
Click click = new Click(true);
click.clicker();
```

This first of the above two lines obviously calls the constructor of `Click`, which sets the `active` variable to `true`. So far so good. The second line is much more interesting. It calls `Click#clicker()`. Let's look at that method:

```
public void clicker() {
    while (active) {
        // <snip>
    }
}
```

This method is the problem. Since you haven't started any other threads, the main thread is the only one you have at that moment, the only thread on which you can execute code. When this loop is executed it only finishes when the `active` variable is set to `false`. As long as it is true, it will keep looping. This means that `Click#clicker()` only returns if `active` is set to `false`. But, you never do that in the loop itself, meaning you need a thread different from the thread executing the loop to change `active`. So, how many threads do we have? 1, the main thread. See the problem? Because the loop never ends, the main thread never reaches the statements in the main method after `click.clicker()`.

## Simple solution

You could just set a fixed number of iterations:

```
public void clicker() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) { // iterate 100 times
        // <snip>
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Or using a for-loop (recommended):

```
public void clicker() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        // <snip>
    }
}
```

This eliminates the need for the `active` variable and hence the need for another thread.

## A somewhat more complicated solution

If you really want the `active` variable, you'll need to have multiple threads. This is conveniently known as "multithreading"<sup>1</sup>, a very complicated topic. Luckily, we only need a bit of it, so it is only a bit complicated.

Don't just call the method `Click#clicker()` like you would normally. This creates your current problem. You'll need a worker thread, which can call the method. The easiest way to create a new thread is to call the constructor of the class `Thread` which takes a single argument of type Runnable. Like this:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        click.clicker();
    }
});
```

This returns relatively quickly and leaves the `Click#clicker()` method running on another thread. Your main thread is now free to execute the other statements and even call `click.toggle()` after a while.

As JB Nizet pointed out, there are some other problems with your code. For example, Swingerinos shouldn't extend Click, but have an instance variable of type `Click` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (as JB Nizet pointed out). Also, you shouldn't need to implement WindowListener to just call `System.exit()` when the window closes if you already call `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`. To get all kinds of feedback (not limited to but including this kind of issues, style and design) on **working code**<sup>2</sup> I highly recommend the StackExchange website codereview.stackexchange.com

1: I by no means consider myself even remotely an expert on threading, so I won't go into it. If you want to know more about it, google it - there's lots of texts on multithreading - or ask another question - if you have a specific problem.
2: this is important: broken code is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up! I ended up trying to thread the method, but as i'm trying to run it from static context it can't directly run  from the main program  so i ended up doing the same thing I originally had - but inside the thread. (So I did Click click = new Click(true); followed by click.clicker();) The GUI opens fine now but the autoclicker doesn't work at all. Sigh. I'll try to figure out what's wrong now.

Comment: I think I know what you did wrong: the thread creation code fragment should be placed in the main method. (To be precise, in the same scope as the variable "click".)  @justSQL

Comment: This is what I currently have, I think I did something wrong :/ http://www.hastebin.com/obavijirub.java